# Difference between ‘spazieren’ and ‘spazieren gehen’

Tags: difference, verb

Is there any difference between these two usages?  I thought they both meant *to walk,* but someone told me (though not sure if they are right or not) that *spazieren* uses different grammar.  I couldn’t find anything on it, so I thought I would post here to clear it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see a grammatical difference, but a (slight) one in meaning. You could compare it to the difference between "walking" (maybe "strolling") and "taking a walk".

> Er spaziert über den Platz.
>
> He walks/strolls across the square.

compared to

> Er geht im Park spazieren.
>
> He takes a walk in the park.

Answer (score 1):

*Spazierengehen* is more closed than *spazieren*.

One the one hand this means, one can say:

> Ich gehe spazieren

and the sentence is complete (expressing i.e. your desire to talk a walk), whereas *ich spaziere* is a fragment only matching to a very primitive question like *Was tust du gerade?* (What are you doing there?)

One the other hand, Hennings example is the only type of extension possible at all. You can add a location or a time where the *Spaziergang* takes place, but that's it.

> Sie spazierte zum Teich, kaufte sich ein Eis und schaute den Schwänen zu.

(She took a walk to the pond, bought a cone of ice cream and looked to the swans) in contrast specifies, where the walk was leading, a construction impossible to be squeezed into a sentence with *spazierengehen*.